# How do I correctly implement a redirect?

Tags: reactjs

I made it so that if the user is already logged in and he tried to go to the login page, then he is redirected to the main page. But when sign out, the redirection occurs only after the page is refreshed (also when sign in). How to fix it?

**route:**

```
const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("token");

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path={'/'} component={Home} />
        <Route path={'/sign-in'} exact render={() => (isLoggedIn ? (<Redirect to="/" />) : (<SignIn />))} />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**sign-out:**

```
const signOut = async () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        await axios.post('sign-out', {});
        setRedirect(true);
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    }
```

Comment: You may want to make the `isLoggedIn` part of some component state so that when a user logs out and state is updated a rerender is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a state in your component and set state according to your login status.Once the state is changed component will re-render automatically.
or else try using a global state like context or redux which will ease your process.